# iOS 14 broken animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, ios14

I started creating an app (not in app store yet) for iOS 13 with SwiftUI. These past few weeks I've been rewriting parts of the app to make it workable for iOS 14 (yes, those damn List separators - when will they be removable???). The app now works, but many of the animations are broken - which means: e.g. instead of a spring animation, a pop-out view I created now appears without animation at all. the animation worked well under iOS 13.6 and 13.7 both on a real device and in the simulator (iPhone SE 2n gen) but not any more under iOS 14. I just downloaded Xcode 12.2 beta (iOS 14.2) but the problem has not been solved. I posted the issue in the feedback app. I would just like to ask if anyone else has a similar issue with animations. I will update this post in case I get a reply from Apple (unlikely...).
The code is exactly the same of course, no matter if I run the app an an iOS 14 simulator or device.

[image: smooth animation iOS 13]

[image: Broken animation iOS 14]

Answer (score 0):

I had also a problem with animations after updating xCode.

In my case was the problem with UICollectionViewCell:

```swift
    // iOS 13
    cell?.contentView.animateScaleTransform(x: 0.9, y: 0.9, duration: 0.1)
```

After building with the new version of xCode I got a crazy mess ...

I was looking for a lot of information but it was fixed too easy:

```swift
    // iOS 14
    cell?.animateScaleTransform(x: 0.9, y: 0.9, duration: 0.1)
```

So, my recommendation for you will be to check the views that you are animating.
Maybe Apple changed something in the hierarchy of default views.
Also, it will be better if you show some code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but my app is built with SwiftUI. I have found out that whether or not the transition of the pop-out animation is visible depends on how many rows are in the list. This is a nested list (over which the timer view appears). The less rows, the smoother the animation... The nested rows are rendered every time when the popup appears and disappears. The main rows are re-rendered also with the change of the popup but additionally every time the timer fires. however, pausing the timer, does not improve the animation at all, but removing all rows does.

Comment: Afer experimenting a bit, I have finally found the culprit... While using complex nested Lists under iOS 13 doesn't seem to cause any stuttering animations, your SwiftUI app will have serious graphics performance problems under iOS 14... So I replaced the outer List by a LazyVStack. Problem solved. The cause might be that the SwiftUI 2.0 implementation of a list is less than optimal.. Apparently under SwiftUI 1.0 Lists were actually wrapped up UITableViews.  I still need to use a List for the inner rows because I need swipe to delete...